# Securing Web API web services, windows authentication

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I need to secure my web services to an existing project, and wasn't sure how to do that.  I'm trying to prevent one user from calling a web service where they can possibly get information about another user.

This is my setup: .NET 4.5 - Web API web services, Windows authentication, ajax (angularjs) front end.  Using NHibernate and SQL server.  I know for every web service I write I can check httpcontext current user, but I don't want to have to do that in every single web service method.  Is there a correct (easier) way to do this?  I read a bit about ASP.NET identity and Owin, but this is way over my head and in addition it only supports entity framework out of the box, I would have to write some custom providers or something to use with NHibernate.  Right no I'm looking into alternatives such as using global.asax or something and enabling the session on the server to store and valid user info.  Is this ok to do, or is there another easier alternative?

Any advice?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you already have your web server configured for Windows Authentication and that part is working.

For authorization, take a look at `System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute` ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute(v=vs.118).aspx)).  Out of the box, this will use roles/AD security groups.  If you have a custom authorization (e.g., stored in your own database), I'd look at implementing `IPrinciple` and setting the `Thread.CurrentPrincipal` in `Global.asax.cs`'s `Application_PostAuthenticateRequest`.  Your implementation of `IPrinciple.IsInRole` would check against the permissions you loaded from your database.